# Posting data to a rails controller from jquery not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, plupload

I am using a JQuery plugin (Plupload) for multiple file uploads on my site. Once the upload completes, I am redirecting the user to an edit page where they can tag and name the photos they just uploaded. I have access to the number of files uploaded (by calling the length on the array that stored the files) and would like to set an instance variable in my photos controller to that so that I can pull the files that were just uploaded.

The redirect is working and the log is showing the parameters as passing the correct integer. Here is what the log shows:

```
  Started POST "/photos?files=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-12 23:09:17 -0400
  Processing by PhotosController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"files"=>"1"}
```

Here is the redirect and the post action in the script:

```
    //redirect after complete
    function attachCallbacks(uploader) {
    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(Up, File, Response) {
        if( (uploader.total.uploaded + 1) == uploader.files.length)
             {
             var target = "/photos";
             var filesAdded = uploader.files.length;
             $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: target + '?files='+filesAdded,
                dataType: 'json'
              });
            window.location = "<%=j photos_path %>";
              }
        })
    }
```

Here is the photos_controller.rb index action where I am trying to set the variable using the parameters:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
 respond_to :html, :json

 def index
   @data = params[:files]
   @user = current_user
   @photos = current_user.photos
   @photo = Photo.new
 end
```

I'd like to limit the photos in the view to only show those just added by calling something like:

```
 @photos = current_user.photos.limit(@data)
```

Thanks, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: No entirely what you intend to be doing using a variable in a controller, and that is why, I've posted a comment - how about passing the files length in the script when redirecting to index as `window.location = "<%=j photos_path(:files => filesAdded) %>";` and limiting the photos in index as `@photos = current_user.photos.order('created_at DESC').limit(params[:files]) if params[:files].present?`

Comment: @prasvin  In fact, this is exactly what @kcurtin wants. The only thing you have to correct is to leave `window.location` as is (`files` param is passed in the `url` option in `$.ajax` call)

Comment: @NashBridges Isn't the ajax call for `create` action & after ajax its redirecting to `index`? The `files` param is already passed in the ajax call. The OP wants to limit the photos in his `index` call and that is why I've added the total files added as `files` params when redirecting to index. I hope I got this one correct.

Comment: @prasvin The problem is that `filesAdded` is a JS variable and cannot be passed to a Rails url helper, not to mention that script is generated and sent to the client *before* user uploads any file. Redirection has to be happened in the `create` action of the `PhotosController`

Comment: @NashBridges- yea, correct `filesAdded` cannot be passed to a Rails url helper as params that way, since when ruby first parses the file it has no `filesAdded` variable . Thanks! . However, since it says `Processing by PhotosController#create as JSON` redirection shouldn't be in the `create`. `window.location` is redirecting to the `index`. Isn't it so?  Have updated the answer too.

Comment: thank you both, i posted this right before bed after trying to figure it out all day..I had no idea you could just add the parameters to the redirect URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entirely what you intend to do **using a variable in a controller** -

How about passing the files length in the script when redirecting to `photos#index` :

```
window.location = "<%=j photos_path %>"+ '?files=' + filesAdded;
```

i.e. redirect to `/photos?files=3`, for 3 files added

Then capturing the `files` params and limiting photos to be rendered in `photos#index`:

```
@photos = current_user.photos.order('created_at DESC').limit(params[:files]) if params[:files].present?
```

Comment: works perfectly - I am using the order('created_at DESC') in my model so I omitted that part. Thank you.